# TO_CHAR failing to set specific format in update

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01481

I'm trying to set a specific field in a record where the legacy code has used a DDMM format DATETIME as a char.  I want to be able to find one specific value that matches something and basically change that one field.  Super simple stuff, right?

```
update MY_TABLE 
set SOME_DATETIME = to_char('0111', 'DDMM') 
where 
FIELDA = 'AA' 
and FIELDB = '2' 
and to_char(SOME_DATETIME, 'DDMM') = '0311' 
and FIELDC = 'ABC'
```

I know for a fact that if I query using to_char(SOME_DATETIME, 'DDMM') = '0311' in a where clause it works but I can't seem to be able to get to change that field.  I get the following error:

```
** ERROR: DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

I've found plenty of examples where people have overcome this error message in a query but not in a "set".

I'm new at Oracle so would love some help.

Thanks

Comment: Kind advice..Please go through Oracle's documentation or some tutorials on `DATE` datatype before messing around with dates.

Comment: `to_char('0111','DDMM')` attempts to convert the character string `'0111'` into a character string (the clue is in the name), which clearly can't be right. If you want a string then `'0111'` is already fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data type of `SOME_DATETIME` is `DATE`, since query works for `to_char(SOME_DATETIME, 'DDMM') = '0311'` conversion. Then proper to use the following :

```
update MY_TABLE 
   set SOME_DATETIME = to_date('0111', 'DDMM') 
 where FIELDA = 'AA' 
   and FIELDB = '2' 
   and to_char(SOME_DATETIME, 'DDMM') = '0311' 
   and FIELDC = 'ABC';
```

where the true conversion should be performed by `to_date` instead of `to_char`.

Comment: It did look like a date but using it as a char elsewhere confused me.  Turns out it was a date.  Cheers.

Comment: @DenizC kolay gelsin dostum.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this part "set SOME_DATETIME = to_char('0111', 'DDMM')". When you use to_char function and specify a Date format, it expects a date. What does he get now? A string. Convert it to some Oracle Date and try again.
for example:

select to_char(to_date('2018-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'DDMM') from dual

Answer (score 1):

```
Select TO_CHAR(date_time_Column,'DD\MM\YYYY HH24:MI)
```

is a good way to improve autput and formatting